# How can I modify the client side of openmeetings project

Tags: flash, client, openmeetings

I want to write client side of the following project

http://openmeetings.apache.org

now it uses flash as client but I don't know where is the source of flash 
and I don't know how can I make JSF client or dot-net client for example

I want to use flash or jsf or dot-net as client , but I don't know how can I do that ?

I want to do these requirements

1. Auto login with user name and password that we already have
2. get  the list of online users
3. Pick someone to start conversatin
4. Chat client will be started by our another desktop program. That program will provide the authentication information.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I don"t think anybody will code you your requirements here. So maybe you better start of coming up with concrete questions or maybe visit their mailing list.